# Node.js double routing issue

Tags: node.js, routes

I have two routes which is getting hit by the same url: 
http://localhost:3000/admin/venues/edit/1234

I would expect this url to only trigger route 2. Why is it also triggering route 1?

Route #1:

```
app.get('/:locality/:category/:venue', require('../views/details/index').index);
```

Route #2:

```
app.get('/admin/venues/edit/:slug', require('../views/admin/index').index))
```

I guess the second route can't understand that it should not trigger on the first param being 'admin'. Can you specify with a RegExp pattern that certain words like 'admin' should be ignored for the first param in route #1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since route 1 is placed before route 2, node will think that "admin" is the value you want to assign to the :locality parameter. Switch the order of your routes and everything should be fine. As a rule of thumb, place routes with parameters at the end of your routing list. Order matters for routes.